# com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, ant, dex

I use ant release and got this error:

```
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:580)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:538)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:519)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

I have [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853460/multiple-dex-files-error-when-compiling-with-ant-or-eclipse), but answers didn't help me

I tried:

- Reinstall android sdk to other dir
- Remove bin/gen dirs and clean project
- Remove and add libs in eclipse
- Change android API from 17 to 10
- [Make sure my bin folder is not included in my build path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define/8071713#8071713)

I have 1 main project and 2 lib projects (Facebook and Expansion files downloader)

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check if the package includes com/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService is reference twice or more in your project settings.

Comment: Thanks @Robin! I use 1 jar lib copies in 2 projects

Answer (score 6):

This exception happens when two identical jars are imported to the projects. Android tries to build the dex file (this is the file where all the java jar's and classes are joined together) it's gets an exception.

The solution is to go though all the jars that you are importing to the project and remove the duplications.
In this case Lcom.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService has been referenced more then once as written above.